NestJS server Upload files deploy on vercel have errors in Logs vercel
I hope you’re having a good day! I’m developing a NestJS server and have implemented a file upload feature that works perfectly on my local server. I can see the uploaded images and their URLs. However, after deploying my NestJS server to Vercel, I encounter a 500 status error, and the logs show the following error:
Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/var/task/src/uploads'


Error Log:
*(node:9) ExperimentalWarning: vm.USE_MAIN_CONTEXT_DEFAULT_LOADER is an experimental feature and might change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/var/task/src/uploads'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1372:26)
    at sync (/var/task/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:74:13)
    at Function.sync (/var/task/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:80:24)
    at new DiskStorage (/var/task/node_modules/multer/storage/disk.js:21:12)
    at module.exports 
  errno: -30,
  code: 'EROFS',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '/var/task/src/uploads'
}
Node.js process exited with exit status: 1. The logs above can help with debugging the issue.
}*

My Code :
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileFieldsInterceptor([{ name: 'image', maxCount: 5 }], {
      limits: { fileSize: 2000000 },

      storage: diskStorage({
        // destination: resolve(__dirname, '..', 'uploads', 'blogCover'),

        // destination: '/tmp/blogCover', // Use /tmp directory

        destination: (req, file, cb) => {
          const dir = '/tmp/blogCover'; // Use /tmp directory
          fs.mkdirSync(dir, { recursive: true }); // Create the directory if it doesn't exist
          cb(null, dir);
        },

        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
          const filename = path
            .parse(file.originalname)
            .name.replace(/\s+/g, '_'); // Remove spaces
          const extension = path.parse(file.originalname).ext;
          return cb(null, `${filename}${extension}`);
        },
      }),

      fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        const extension = path.parse(file.originalname).ext;

        if (extension !== '.png') {
          return cb(new BadRequestException('must be pngs'), false);
        }
        return cb(null, true);
      },
    }),
  )

method UploadFile:
  UploadFile(
    @Res() res,
    @Req() req,
    @Body() body: any,
    // @UploadedFile() image: Express.Multer.File,
    @UploadedFiles() files: { image?: Express.Multer.File[] },
  ) {
    try {
      let fileUrl;
      const pictures = [];
      // console.log('uploadcontroler:', body, files);
      // console.log ('USER : ', req.user);
      if (!files.image) {
        throw new BadRequestException('select (img first .png)');
      }
      const getImagsInFiles = files.image.map((img) => {
        // console.log(img, 'img in the map');
        // console.log(img.filename, 'filename img in the map');
        fileUrl = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/uploads/blogCover/${img.filename}`;
        return pictures.push({ img: fileUrl, Picid: new Date() });
      });

      // Save images or data to JSON in /tmp
      const filePath = path.join('/tmp', 'data.json');
      fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(pictures));

      console.log('FILEURL', fileUrl);
      // * saved upload pictures from user
      this.uploadServices.saveUserPictures({
        userId: req.user.id,
        url: pictures,
      });

      return res.send({
        data: { picsUploads: pictures, countPics: getImagsInFiles },
        message: 'image is uploaded',
        status: 201,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('upload file error', err);
      return res.send({
        data: { err: err },
        message: 'select image first extension:image.png',
        status: 404,
      });
    }
  }

What I've Tried:
I attempted to use the /tmp directory for temporary file storage, but it still resulted in errors when deployed.
What is this error: EROFS: read-only file system, open? And how do I fix it #314
but this link is not help me .
this my code nestjs i try upload file :
thanks every one for help me for fix this issue  .

I found a solution for the 500 status error when trying to upload files to my NestJS server deployed on Vercel. The issue arises because Vercel's serverless architecture does not support persistent file writing; it can only write to a temporary directory, which is cleared after each request.
To handle file uploads effectively, I recommend using cloud storage services such as AWS S3, Google Cloud Storage, or similar. Here’s how you can implement this:
1 - Set Up a Cloud Storage Bucket: Create a bucket in your preferred cloud storage service to store your uploaded files.
2 - Use SDKs: Integrate the respective SDK (e.g., AWS SDK for S3) into your NestJS application to handle file uploads directly to the cloud storage.
3 - Update Your Upload Logic: Modify your file upload logic to send the files to the cloud storage instead of trying to save them locally.
4 - Return URLs: After uploading, return the accessible URLs of the uploaded files to the client for use.
By following this approach, you'll avoid the limitations of Vercel's serverless environment and ensure that your files are stored reliably.
